# Receber as teclas numéricas para fazer algumas funções igual para todas elas no switch em uma calculadora

Tags: javascript, loop, switch

```
  switch (e.target.value) {
        case "A/C":
            console.log('ae')
            break;
        case "C":
            break;
        case "X":
            break;
        case ".":
            break;
        case "%":
            break;
        case "-":
            break;
        case "√":
            break;
        case "+":
            break;
        case "÷":
            break;
        case "=":
            break;
        **case IsNumber():
            console.log('é um numero')
            break;**
    }
```

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora em JS. Gostaria de receber as teclas numéricas para fazer algumas funções igual para todas elas.
É possivel reconhecer se a tecla clicada.value é um numero no switch? Ou terei de fazer tecla por tecla, ou talvez um if statemente, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O propósito de se usar um switch ao invés de if/else, é que o switch cria uma hashtable e encontra o resultado por associação. Mesmo que fosse possível declarar uma função no switch, não teria como encontrar o match por associação, logo não seria diferente de um if/else.

Em outras palavras, sim, você terá que usar um if, ou então colocar todas as opções dentro do switch.

```
switch (e.target.value) {
    case "A/C":
        console.log('ae')
        break;
    case "C":
        break;
    case "X":
        break;
    case ".":
        break;
    case "%":
        break;
    case "-":
        break;
    case "√":
        break;
    case "+":
        break;
    case "÷":
        break;
    case "=":
        break;
    default:
        if (!isNaN(e.target.value)) {
            console.log('é um numero')
        }
}
```

Ou:

```
switch (e.target.value) {
    case "A/C":
        console.log('ae')
        break;
    case "C":
        break;
    case "X":
        break;
    case ".":
        break;
    case "%":
        break;
    case "-":
        break;
    case "√":
        break;
    case "+":
        break;
    case "÷":
        break;
    case "=":
        break;
    case "1": case "2": case "3": case "4": case "5": case "6": case "7": case "8": case "9": case "0":
        console.log('é um numero')
        break;
}
```

Comment: Beleza. Muito Obrigado !!